# How can I index a scene with no data file for a measurement?

Tags: open-data-cube

When indexing a scene that does not have a data file for a measurement defined in the product's definition, what is the best practice for indexing the scene such that ODC returns no data for it (more specifically, the data variable should be filled with the `nodata` value for that measurement for that time)?

Can we specify an empty string (`''`) for `path` for the measurement in the dataset document to do this, or something similarly simple?

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to create a raster with no data and refer to it every time you do not have data for that particular measurement/band/layer.
This works if the input dataset has always the same extent and projection.

Comment: Thanks, Michele.

That is the workaround we hoped to avoid, but maybe it can be a 1 pixel file containing the `nodata` value. ODC would then fill the rest of the data for that data variable (`measurement`) for that scene with the `nodata` value as well.